# How do I shorten that specific code in C#?

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

I am a beginner C# learner. I am trying to learn through an app called SoloLearn.
In the app, it wants me to replace 3 and its multiples in a series of numbers with "*".
For example; the input is n number, let's say 7, the output should go "12 * 45 * 7" (without spaces)
I tried this, it worked but these two "ifs" at the end make my eyes bleed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            //your code goes here
            for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++)
            {
                if (x%3==0)
                Console.Write("*");
                if (x%3==0)
                continue;
    
                {
                     Console.Write(x);   
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I played around it a little but can't seem to find any way around it.
How would you shorten these only with the content in this code given?

Comment: Take look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) and you'll see that you can use a block after `if`...

Comment: `for (var x = 1; x <= number; x++) Console.Write(x % 3 == 0?"*": x.ToString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `continue` statement there. Instead of two `if`s you could use an `if` and an `else`, e.g.:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++)
{
    if (x % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    else
    {
         Console.Write(x);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
    var seq = Enumerable.Range(1, number).Select(x=>x%3==0?"*":x.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", seq));
}
```

And I could, of course, shorten it further to a single line, but that just seems excessive. There's probably also a way to get an implicit `ToString()` conversion.

Comment: `string.Concat(seq)` is a slightly cleaner way to do `string.Join("", seq)`.

Answer (score 0):

The slightly shorter version of the `for` loop is this:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++)
{
    Console.Write(x % 3 == 0 ? "*" : $"{x}");
}
```

Comment: It's called the "Ternary Operator"